# Как реализуется система пользователей на сайтах типа Я.Диска?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, express

Скорее всего сейчас заминусуют, но все же. Вот объясните как для тупого пж( Я ни как не могу в это въехать.

В моем представлении это работает так: на сервер уходит post запрос с логином и паролем, на сервере это обрабатывается, создается jwt и как то обрабатывается на клиенте... а вот дальше?

Как сайт понимает что у `username-1` рабочая папка это `username-1-folder` и взаимодействовать клиент должен именно с ней(+ какие нибудь права, что бы хацкер какой не мог получить доступ не к своей папке)??

Накидайте статьи, объеснения своими словами, видео на ютубе, что угодно. Заранее огромное спасибо(

Comment: Ну прямо так и понимает, наверное — где-то в базе данных сервера записано, что пользователь `username-1` имеет доступ к папке `username-1-folder`, и при каждом обращении к папке выполняется проверка доступа путём поиска такой записи в базе данных

Comment: @andreymal т е при каждом обращении к серверу с попыткой добавить/удалить/изменить файл должна происходить проверка, имеет ли пользователь права на работу с этой папкой. я правильно понял?

Comment: На серверах типа яндекс диска  нет никаких папок как вы их себе представляете. Есть большая база данных